# Creating a translated sample by subtracting mode

Tags: self-study, data-transformation, mean, biostatistics, mode

> Consider a sample $x_1,...,x_n$ which we will call the original sample. To create a translated sample $x_1+c,...,x_n+c$, we add a constant $c$ to each sample point.
>
> Let $y_i=x_i+c, \;i=1,...,n$
>
> Then $\bar y=\bar x +c$
>
> From the table below, to compute the arithmetic mean of the time interval between menstrual periods, it would be more convenient to work with numbers that are closer to zero rather than $28$, which is the mode.
>
> [image]

My questions are:

- Why is $28$ subtracted for the translated sample?
- Do you always subtract the mode to create a translated sample or would any value work? Why is this?
- Is it more accurate when you choose the mode rather than subtracting, say, 23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the mean, I wouldn't use the method of subtracting a constant. I would just read the data into a favourite program.

That said, the principle is that

mean of variable $=$ mean of (variable $-$ constant) $+$ constant

so that what you subtract at the start of work you can just add again at the end. So, the question is what constant to use, and in principle any constant is fine, but for hand calculations, with a calculator or even pencil and paper, some constants are better than others.

In this case, the data are integers and the mode is an integer, so subtracting the mode would be especially convenient. However, this is not an especially general method. For example, a mode may not be well defined. But it really doesn't matter much because, on the evidence here, this is no more than a matter of making pre-computer calculations easy.

It's good practice to give references for book citations. The book might be interesting or useful to readers.